# Jekyll ignores baseurl

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to create a Jekyll (2.5.3) powered site and to publish it to GitHub pages using [DOCter](https://github.com/cfpb/docter/) but I have an hard time making the assets working properly.

In my `_config.yml` I have defined the `base_url` as indicated in the [Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/#project-page-url-structure)

```
baseurl: '/docter-test'
```

In my layout I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/syntax.css">
```

but when I generate the static site the CSS are not properly referred.

Instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/docter-test/assets/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/docter-test/assets/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/docter-test/assets/css/syntax.css">
```

I get

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/syntax.css">
```

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It turned out that Jekyll doesn't like the '-' in the baseurl. Updating to `baseurl: '/doctertest'` fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you set your `baseurl: '/docter-test'` in `_config.yml`; `jekyll serve` at `http://127.0.0.1:4000/docter-test/`.

If you do `jekyll serve --baseurl ''`, this will overwrite your settings and break links and assets paths. And your site will be served at `http://127.0.0.1:4000/`.